# Why isn't my update panel working?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, user-controls, updatepanel

### Update

Apparently this issue has nothing to do with the control. I've added other UpdatePanels onto my page and none of them are working either.

We thought maybe it was because the target framework was old, so we updated the whole project from .NET 4.0 to 4.6.1, hoping that would fix it, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas on what could cause UpdatePanels to not work at all?

I've used UpdatePanels on plenty of other projects and pages, so I know what to do to get them to work under normal circumstances...

It does have a master page...I don't know if that makes a difference. I'm new to those.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" ClientIDMode="Static" MasterPageFile="~/Primary.Master" CodeBehind="Overpayment_Referral_Form_New.aspx.vb" Inherits="Overpayment_Referral_Form_New" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Primary.Master" %>
```

---

### Original Post

Ok, so I have a user control to do a search with some drop down lists and text boxes like so:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProviderType" CssClass="InlineSpacer">
   Provider Type:
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartyClass" runat="server" Width="128" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Label>
```

And later:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="InlineSpacer">
   First Name:
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" CssClass="InlineSpacer">
   Last Name:
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Label>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFullName" Visible="False" CssClass="InlineSpacer">
   Provider Name:
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Label>
```

The drop down list is populated in code behind. When it changes, the ToggleFields function runs which flips the visibility on the labels above. I currently have a custom event defined which I raise inside the selectedIndexChanged handler:

```
Public Event ProviderTypeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
...
Private Sub ddlPartyClass_SelectedIndexChanged( _
            ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs _
            ) Handles ddlPartyClass.SelectedIndexChanged

    ToggleFields()
    RaiseEvent ProviderTypeChanged(sender, e)
End Sub
```

(I did not name or create most of this actually, so I apologize for the weird conventions and formatting. At least they are weird to me...)

I've put this control into my page here:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SearchControlsUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="AllSearchControls">
            <div id="ProviderSearchControlDiv" class="SearchControlDiv">
                <uc1:ContainedProviderSearch runat="server" ID="ProviderSearchControl" SearchContext="OverpaymentReferralForm"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ProviderSearchControl" EventName="ProviderTypeChanged"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I also currently have my page's script manager registering the control as asynchronous. My script manager's EnablePartialRendering attribute is set to 'True'. I have tried every variation of the control being used for the trigger, where the update panel is (inside the control, on the page with the control inside, both), setting the trigger declaratively or programmatically, having the UpdateMode set to Conditional and Always, and I cannot get the visibility of those labels to flip without a whole page refresh.

There have been things I tried that will flip them with a page refresh, and some where the postback was asynchronous with no page refresh but also no change inside the update panel. I've stepped through and watched the visibilities get flipped, watched the Update method of the UpdatePanel being called explicitly with the correct values set, and still nothing happened on the page. I'm at a loss. So if anyone can find what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it. I've been through every post on here I can find about similar issues and none of the fixes have worked.

Please let me know if you want some other code piece posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm not entirely sure why this broke it, but my page was inheriting from another page which had **overridden the Render()** method. After commenting that override out, my update panels started working. This is an old system and we are actually planning on getting rid of that page that mine is inheriting from, but yeah, that was the problem.

So moral of the story, if nothing else makes sense as to why your UpdatePanel is not working. Make sure you (or someone else) isn't doing any *weird stuff* with the **Render()** method.

Answer (score 0):

1>You may replace UpdatePanel by Ajax toolkit update panel..
2>You may also changed upadate mode partial in update 'SearchControlsUpdatePanel' then in 'Public Event ProviderTypeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)' event write 
SearchControlsUpdatePanel.Update() method..

Comment: The SearchControlsUpdatePanel is in a different file. It can't be referenced from the control's page, which is where that Event is. And aren't what do you mean replace it with Ajax toolkit update panel? They're the same thing.

Comment: Oh, so the Ajax toolkit update panel...I don't know if that would work or not, but I do know that it adds build time and page load time, which are two things I definitely don't want on this project. It's already bloated enough as it is.